# time nohup ./script --> the time hasn't been logged

Tags: scripting, shell-scripting, time, firefox, background-process

I need to measure the time that Firefox takes to build itself from the source code. Here's what I do normaly:

```
nohup ./mach build > my_log.log &
```

I then prepended `time` to it:

```
time nohup ./mach build > my_log.log &
```

However, this hasn't made it generate any report about the time spent, at the end of the `my_log` file.

Why not? How to fix it?

Comment: I think you may need a 2&1 redirect

Comment: Have you try `nohup time ./mach build >my_log.log  2>&1 &`

Comment: this might be smarter: `nohup time -o build.out ./mach build >my_log.log  2>&1 &`  the output from `time` is in build.out/,  ( or even add `--verbose` after the `-o build.out` )

Answer (score 1):

In your second attempt you measure the execution time of `nohup` command itself. So to get the build time you should put `time` after `nohup`:

```
nohup time ./mach build >my_log.log  2>&1 &
```

Also redirect the `STDERR` is good practice.

And as mentioned in comment you can have dedicated log for `time` command:

```
nohup time -o build.time ./mach build >my_log.log  2>&1 &
```